# Derivation 9.97 in Jaynes' Probability Theory

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, taylor-expansion

In page 298 of Jaynes' Probability Theory: the Logic of Science, equation (9.97), Jaynes says:

> We expect that, if hypothesis $H$ is true, then $n_k$ will be close to $np_k$, in the sense that the difference $|n_k-np_k|$ will grow with $n$ only as $\sqrt n$. Call this 'condition A'. Then using the expansion $\log(x) = (x-1)-(x-1)^2/2+...$, we find that
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^mn_k\log\left[\frac{n_k}{np_k}\right] = \frac 1 2\sum_k\frac{(n_k-np_k)^2}{np_k} + O\left(\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\right)$$

In the above, $\sum_kp_k = 1$ and $\sum_kn_k=n$, where $n$ is the total number of trials in a series of Bernoulli trials and $n_k$ is the number of trials that had outcome $k$.

I'd like to know how he got from that expansion to the quoted equation, especially given that the squared term in the expansion has negative sign.

--EDIT to add info--

Jaynes' nomenclature confused me a bit. He calls hypotheses of the type "there are $m$ possible outcomes of an experiment, each being observed with probability $p_k$ independent of previous or future repetitions of that experiment" the "Bernoulli class." $n_k$ is the number of performed experiments that had outcome $k$, $n$ is the total number of experiments performed. But that is all that's defined by Jaynes, and all that's known about the hypotheses.

(A thought occurs: what if Jaynes meant that condition A is that $|n_k -np_k| \approx O(1/\sqrt n)$? I haven't explored this possibility to know whether it makes sense.)

Comment: I don't understand "$n_k$ is the number of Bernoulli trials with outcome $k$".  A Bernoulli trial has outcomes 0 and 1.  Do you mean $n_k$ is a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p_k$?  But that would contradict $\sum_k n_k=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_k (n_k-np_k)^2/np_k$ is Pearson's chi-squared statistic.  The left side of the equation is the log likelihood ratio of the mle for the multinomial distribution vs the probabilities under the null hypothesis, the $p_k$'s.  A common result is that 2*log likelihood ratio (likelihood alternative/likelihood null) has a chi-squared distribution under the null hypothesis with df = k-1.  It is also well known that the Pearson Chi-squared statistic for the goodness of fit test also has k-1 df.  The left and right sides of the equation have the same asymptotic distribution under the null hypothesis.  The proof of either of these results should help.

As a side note, the meaning of $n_k-np_k$ growing with rate $\sqrt{n}$ could mean that since $n_k \sim binomial(n, p_k)$,

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(n_k-np_k) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, p_k(1-p_k)) \text{ as } n\to \infty  $, the standard normal approximation to the binomial.

Or it could mean that $\vert n_k-np_k \vert = O_p(\sqrt{n}) \text{ or } O(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: could you expand a bit?

Comment: @nbubis I could indeed, but probably not until tomorrow. Which part do you want expanded?

Comment: Indeed that's Pearson's chi-squared statistic, and the point of this passage of the book is exactly to "prove" that the log-likelihood ratio (which Jaynes calls psi) is approximately proportional to the chi-squared under certain circumstances, and that's exactly the proof that I don't understand x) And if you could replicate and/or point to the proof that they have the same asymptotic distribution, that'd help, though then I'd be wondering how the hell Jaynes came up with that log series expansion thing.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho  check out the proof here... http://www.unc.edu/courses/2006spring/ecol/145/001/docs/lectures/lecture14.htm

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best I can get is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^m n_k\log\left[\frac{n_k}{n p_k}\right]
& = \sum_{k=1}^m n_k\left[\left(\frac{n_k}{n p_k}-1\right)-\frac12\left(\frac{n_k}{n p_k}-1\right)^2+O\left(\left(\frac{n_k}{n p_k}-1\right)^3\right)\right] \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^m n_k\left[-\frac12\left(\frac{n_k}{n p_k}\right)^2+\frac{2n_k}{n p_k}-\frac32+O\left(\left(\frac{n_k-n p_k}{n p_k}\right)^3\right)\right] \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^m -\frac{n_k^3}{2n^2 p_k^2}+\frac{2n_k^2}{n p_k}-\frac{3n_k}2+n_k O\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{n p_k}\right)^3\right) \qquad\text{condition A} \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^m -\frac{n_k^3}{2n^2 p_k^2}+\frac{2n_k^2}{n p_k}-\frac{3n_k}2+n_k O\left(n^{-3/2}\right) \\
& = \left[\sum_{k=1}^m -\frac{n_k^3}{2n^2 p_k^2}+\frac{2n_k^2}{n p_k}\right]-\frac{3n}2+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

But something isn't right.  Your desired expression is $O(1)$, while the expansion appears to be $O(\sqrt n)$: condition A says $n_k=np_k+O(\sqrt n)$, so that the left hand side is
$$\sum_k(np_k+O(\sqrt n))\log(1+O(n^{-1/2})=\sum_k(np_k+O(\sqrt n))O(n^{-1/2}).$$  I think we need to use something about the definition of $p_k$, $n_k$, and $n$.

Comment: I have edited the original post to add more information.